# Error Eigen library on linux

Tags: c++, eigen, triplet

I have implemented this code with Eigen library to have Triplet structure. 
This code works very well in my project on my Mac OS X. However the same code don't work on Linux platform.

```
 Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> spdiags(const MatrixXd& B, const     
      Eigen::Matrix<int, 1,1>& d, size_t m, size_t n)
 {
          Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(m,n);
          typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
          std::vector<T> triplets;
          triplets.reserve(std::min(m,n)*d.size());   
          for (int k = 0; k < d.size(); k++) 
          {
            int i_min = std::max(0, -d(k));
            int i_max = std::min(m - 1, n - d(k) - 1);
            int B_idx_start = m >= n ? d(k) : 0;
            for (int i = i_min; i <= i_max; i++) {
            triplets.push_back( T(i, i+k, B(B_idx_start + i, k)) );
          }
       A.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());

      std::cout << "Row\tCol\tVal" <<std::endl;
      for (int k=0; k < A.outerSize(); ++k)
      {
          for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(A,k); it; ++it)
          {
              std::cout << it.row() << "\t"; // row index
              std::cout << it.col() << "\t";  
              std::cout << it.value() << std::endl;
          }
      }

     return A;

    }
```

I have this error only on Linux (there is no error on Mac). The code source of the file `DenseCoeffsBase.h` is the same:

```
"/usr/local/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:114: 
Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::CoeffReturnType 
Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::operator() 
    (Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::Index, 
     Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::Index) const 
[with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; 
      Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::CoeffReturnType = const double&; 
      Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::Index = long int]:
Assertion `row >= 0 && row < rows() && col >= 0 && col < cols()' failed."
```

Any ideas?

Here is an MVC as asked :

```
#include<Eigen/Sparse>

#include <Eigen/Sparse>

#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<Eigen/Eigenvalues>

    Matrix<int, 1, 1> d1; d1(0)=0;
    MatrixXd d0; d0.resize(1,5);

    d0(0)=10;d0(1)=20;d0(2)=30;d0(3)=30;d0(4)=40;d0(5)=50;

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Diag_laplacian=test.spdiags(d0,d1,5,5);

    //-------------- 
    //the result must be like this : 
    Row Col Val
    0   0   10
    1   1   20
    2   2   30
    3   3   30  
    4   4   40
```

Comment: You have a mismatched parenthesis and your formatting make understanding your code difficult.

Comment: What compiler and what flags?

Comment: Also, you need to include what the input parameters are. My guess is that the `B` matrix is too small for the index range.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. These are the flags: LIBS += -lgsl -lgslcblas -lX11 -lpthread -llapack  -lm -fopenmp

 And the input is just a Matrix<1,N> and d is also a vector    Matrix<int, 1, 1> d1; d1(0)=0;

Comment: So... which line is 114?

Comment: the line 114 is in the file DenseCoeffsBase.h (Eigen files), and this is it : 

/** \returns the coefficient at given the given row and column.
      *
      * \sa operator()(Index,Index), operator[](Index)
      */
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType operator()(Index row, Index col) const
    {
      eigen_assert(row >= 0 && row < rows()
          && col >= 0 && col < cols());
      return derived().coeff(row, col);
    }

Comment: @marc If you really want to see the Eigen code, it's [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/DenseCoeffsBase_8h_source.html).

Comment: @ananass Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Make sure it includes the input matrices. Also, what version of (I assume) gcc are you using?

Comment: I've poster a MCVE (I edit my question), how can i know the version on my gcc ?

Comment: That's not a MCVE (I can't copy it and it runs), but one thing I noticed is that IMHO the indices in `B` are swapped: It should be `B(k, B_idx_... + i)`

Comment: the indexes are good, because it works well on my Mac OSX.
For the MCVE, you want one function that contains all the code?

Comment: if you copy the code with the includes i wrote, you will have the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, my dear sir/madam, is an MCVE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core> 
#include <Eigen/Sparse> 
using namespace Eigen;

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> spdiags(const MatrixXd& B,
    const Eigen::Matrix<int, 1, 1>& d, size_t m, size_t n)
{
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(m, n);
    typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
    std::vector<T> triplets;
    triplets.reserve(std::min(m, n)*d.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < d.size(); k++)
    {
        int i_min = std::max(0, -d(k));
        int i_max = std::min(m - 1, n - d(k) - 1);
        int B_idx_start = m >= n ? d(k) : 0;
        for (int i = i_min; i <= i_max; i++)
            triplets.push_back(T(i, i + k, B(B_idx_start + i, k)));
    }
    A.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());

    std::cout << "Row\tCol\tVal" << std::endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < A.outerSize(); ++k)
    {
        for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(A, k); it; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << it.row() << "\t"; // row index
            std::cout << it.col() << "\t";
            std::cout << it.value() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return A;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 1, 1> d1; d1(0) = 0;
    MatrixXd d0; d0.resize(1, 5);

    // Note that you *have* to use (x,y) indices on a MatrixXd
    // Otherwise, you get a different assertion failure
    d0(0,0) = 10; d0(0,1) = 20;
    d0(0,2) = 30; d0(0,3) = 30;
    d0(0,4) = 40;
    // d0(0,5) = 50; // OUT OF BOUNDS!!!

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Diag_laplacian = spdiags(d0, d1, 5, 5);
}
```

The expected result is (as you stated):

```
Row Col Val  
0   0   10  
1   1   20  
2   2   30  
3   3   30  
4   4   40
```

To reproduce the results, I can either use VS (2013 in my case) or g++ (i.e. it's not Linux vs. Mac). As you are using g++, I will as well.

To reproduce the behavior you described on the Linux build, I compiled with

```
g++ -O3 -I"C:\usr\include" Source.cpp -o a.exe
```

Running `a.exe` gave me (as you stated)

> Assertion failed: row >= 0 && row < rows() && col >= 0 && col < cols(), file C:\usr\include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h, line 114

Debugging it showed me that it fails on the line

```
triplets.push_back(T(i, i + k, B(B_idx_start + i, k)));
```

when `i == 1`. Why? Exactly as @marc and I stated. `B` is not shaped/sized as you use it. Changing `B(B_idx_start + i, k)` with `B(k, B_idx_start + i)` resolves the issue.

Now, why does it work on the Mac? The answer has to do with the error itself. It's an assertion error. [Assertions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) are not checked when `NDEBUG` is defined. So you probably compiled using something like

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -O3 -I"C:\usr\include" Source.cpp -o a.exe
```

on the Mac, and it ran fine, as then the assertions are ignored:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(_Expression)  ((void)0)
#else
```

So, if there is an assertion failure, why does it work when we define `NDEBUG`? The answer to that is that the data pointer points to the first of five allocated `doubles`. Using the correct indexing, we should get `index = k*1 + (B_idx_start + i)`, and since in this case `k==0` and `B_idx_start==0`, we get `index=i`. This is within the bounds and therefore we don't get an out of bounds exception. Using the incorrect indexing, we get `index = (B_idx_start + i)*1 + k` which again, results in `index=i`. If the size of the matrix was (for example) 2x5, then we would have gotten an out of bounds exception.

Comment: thank you very much for you good and clear explanations. I will keep on mind the definition of a MVC next time i'll ask a question. For the story of assertion, i did not know what it is before. I'll make some research work to know more about this. thank you